# Search And Replace With Regular Expression webuilder

Tags: regex, search, replace, expression, notepad++

I want to find and replace this statements  in all project files.

Search:

```
MD.QryLoadSupplycode.Value
MD.QryLoadClientname.Value
```

Result :

```
MD.QryLoadSupplycode.AsString
MD.QryLoadClientname.AsString
```

Please Help!!!!

I have tried do

```
Search: MD\.[A-Z,a-z,0-9]+\.Value (yes found)
Replace: MD\.[A-Z,a-z,0-9]+\.AsString (not work)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're trying to use your pattern in your replacement instead of matching and capturing the pattern when you execute your search.

By placing a capturing group `()` around your search pattern, we can reference back to what was matched in the replacement call.

```
Search: (MD\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)Value
Replace: \1AsString
```

**Note**: By having commas inside your character class, you're matching literals ( *not separating the syntax* )